# adding template from plugin to wordpress contained with built in wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i added my custom template to wordpress from my plugin by following code

```
function override_single_template( $single_template ){
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "recipes"){
        $single_template  = plugins_url('/recipe-single-page-template.php',__FILE__);
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'override_single_template',10);
```

but i cant use get_header() or get_footer() functions or any other wordpress function in my template and i got following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()
```

whate should i do to use wordpress built in functions?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer
i should add wp-load.php file to my template to use wordpress functions
simply added following code to header and now there is no problem

```
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
```